# Can run android SOAP on emulator but not on device

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I've gotten my project to be able to run on the emulator but it will not run on my device, does anybody know what the causes of this might be? I have the code below, and when I try to run it on my device and step through it I get the famous `org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG` error

```
private static final String NAMESPACE   =   "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL         =   "http://work/today/Service1.asmx";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION =  "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
private static final String METHOD_NAME =  "HelloWorld";

public void getMessage() {

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);


    MarshalBase64 mbase = new MarshalBase64();// marshal is used to serialize the byte array


    //Create envelope
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);


    //Set output SOAP object
    envelope.bodyOut=request;
    envelope.env = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"; 
    envelope.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.ENC2003;
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


    //Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE at = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    //AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

    mbase.register(envelope);

    try {
        //Invoke web service
        //at.getConnection();
        at.debug=true;
        at.setXmlVersionTag("<!--?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding= \"UTF-8\" ?-->");
        at.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        //Get the response
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        //Assign it to fahren static variable
        message = response.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

The code errors out at this line: `at.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);`

The response.dump is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-   serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</h2>
  <h3>You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you    supplied.</h3>
</fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't understand how it can work on the emulator but not on the device it doesn't make sennse to me... I have done a lot of research on the internet along with on SO but still have got nothing in regards to `ksoap2` or `SOAP web services` to resolve my problem.... If anybody can offer some advice it would be greatly appreciated, thanks !

Comment: where is your server running? on the same machine?

Comment: Yes I made a website in `IIS` and I can't perform the `at.call()` when I try to run it on my device but it works when I make the call using localhost and the emulator

Comment: can you replace that WORK with your LOCAL IP address and give it a try?